# Add title to the group from data attribute value

Tags: jquery

I have got a number of holidays in my html:

```
<ul class="sort-list">
   <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="14/02/2016">Valentine's Day</li>
   <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="25/12/2016">Christmas</li>
   <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="25/12/2016">New Years</li>
   <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="01/01/2016">New Year's Day</li>
   <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="31/10/2016">Halloween</li>
</ul>
```

And have managed to group them by the date in right order by using the jquery:

```
(function($){
var container = $(".sort-list");
var items = $(".sort-item");

items.each(function() {
   // Convert the string in 'data-event-date' attribute to a more
   // standardized date format
   var BCDate = $(this).attr("data-event-date").split("/");
   var standardDate = BCDate[1]+" "+BCDate[0]+" "+BCDate[2];
   standardDate = new Date(standardDate).getTime();
   $(this).attr("data-event-date", standardDate);

});

items.sort(function(a,b){
    a = parseFloat($(a).attr("data-event-date"));
    b = parseFloat($(b).attr("data-event-date"));
    return a>b ? -1 : a<b ? 1 : 0;
}).each(function(){
    container.prepend(this);
});

})(jQuery);
```

What I need to achieve is to add each date of the group above it if they have got the same value of data attribute for example:

**01/01/2016**
New Year's Day
**14/02/2016**
Valentine's Day
**31/12/2016**
Halloween
**31/12/2016**
New Years
Christmas

Please see my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qq8mhw97/1/

I do really appreciate your help on this task.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```js
(function($) {
  var container = $(".sort-list");
  var items = $(".sort-item");

  items.each(function() {
    // Convert the string in 'data-event-date' attribute to a more
    // standardized date format
    var BCDate = $(this).attr("data-event-date").split("/");
    var standardDate = BCDate[1] + " " + BCDate[0] + " " + BCDate[2];
    standardDate = new Date(standardDate).getTime();
    $(this).attr("data-event-date", standardDate);
  });

  items.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = parseFloat($(a).attr("data-event-date"));
    b = parseFloat($(b).attr("data-event-date"));
    return a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;
  }).each(function() {
    container.prepend(this);
    if ($(this).next().text() == $(this).attr("data-event-date")) $(this).next().remove()
    container.prepend('<li>' + $(this).attr("data-event-date") + '</li')

  });
  $('li:not(".sort-item")').each(function() {
    var d = new Date(parseInt($(this).text(), 10));
    $(this).text(d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear())
  })
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sort-list">
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="14/02/2016">Valentine's Day</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="25/12/2016">Christmas</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="25/12/2016">New Years</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="14/06/2016">Bastille Day</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="01/01/2016">New Year's Day</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="31/10/2016">Halloween</li>
</ul>
```